# How deployment order is evaluated in weblogic 12

Tags: deployment, weblogic

There are two application which I am trying to deploy on weblogic with default deployment order (i.e. 100). I want to know which application is deployed first? As per weblogic documentation it will deploy in alphabetical order when the deployment order is same. I want to know what logic it use for alphabetic order. Does it consider only first letter or it checks in-depth. I did few experiment and observed that it rely on first letter only. e.g. I have two wars - abc.war and adc.war. Ideally it should deploy first abc.war then adc.war but it doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

The deployment order can be changed int he deployments tab. You can have the abc.war be set to a higher priority than the adc.war. While deploying, choose the order you would like. As far as I am aware, there is more to it than alphabetical order since I have seen deployments being deployed in non-alphabetical order. By setting the order in the deployments tab, you can control it.

Comment: Thanks. This I am already aware of. I don't want to manually select the deployment order..